# Google apps script loop mises an iteration

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an array I am trying to remove entry if a particular string is found
The code is skipping an entry in the loop to check

```
unction test(){
  var Concat_names = ["Test 1-Coms-2A Up", "Test 1-Included Units-10G", "test 2-Included Units-1000 Sa", "test 2-Percentage-MB"];
  for (var i in Concat_names) {
    console.log(Concat_names[i]);
    var check_included_units = Concat_names[i].includes("Included Units");
    console.log(check_included_units)
    if (check_included_units == true) {
      Concat_names.splice(i,1);
    }
    else if (check_included_units == false){
      continue;
    }
  }
  console.log(Concat_names);
}
```

The output is as below-

[image]

Please suggest what is wrong here and how to fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, when `Concat_names.splice(i, 1)` is run, `Concat_names` is changed. By this, `i` is changed. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue. In this case, how about looping from the last element? When this is reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var Concat_names = ["Test 1-Coms-2A Up", "Test 1-Included Units-10G", "test 2-Included Units-1000 Sa", "test 2-Percentage-MB"];
for (var i = Concat_names.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // I modified this line.
  console.log(Concat_names[i]);
  var check_included_units = Concat_names[i].includes("Included Units");
  console.log(check_included_units)
  if (check_included_units == true) {
    Concat_names.splice(i, 1);
  } else if (check_included_units == false) {
    continue;
  }
}
console.log(Concat_names); // [ 'Test 1-Coms-2A Up', 'test 2-Percentage-MB' ]
```

- As another approache, I think that you can also use the following script.

```js
var Concat_names = ["Test 1-Coms-2A Up", "Test 1-Included Units-10G", "test 2-Included Units-1000 Sa", "test 2-Percentage-MB"];
var res = Concat_names.filter(e => !e.includes("Included Units"));
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike -san, when you do ```for (var i = Concat_names.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)``` why does the reverse iteration work and not the forward here?

Comment: @Alicia Stone Thank you for replying. About `why does the reverse iteration work and not the forward here?`, in the case of your script, for example, when `Concat_names.splice(i, 1)` is run with `i = 0`, the element of `i = 0` of `Concat_names` is removed. By this, as the next loop, when `i` is `1`, the 2nd element in the original array is skipped. On the other hand, when the loop is started from the last element, even after `Concat_names.splice(i, 1)` is run with `i=3` in the 1st loop, after the 2nd loop, all elements can be checked. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Alicia Stone In the case that the base situation is changed by deleting, the reverse loop might be useful. As a sample situation, in the case of a Spreadsheet, when the row is deleted by a condition, the script might be simple by the reverse loop.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike- san, which will be a more reliable code here the first code or the second one with filter method